# Can I insulate main floorboards overhead hvac/ducts in basement?

Tags: hvac, insulation, floor, basement-insulation

My Hvac is in unfinished basement and part of it is crawl space which is rock. Built 1900. Is it okay to insulate my exposed floor boards of main house? Which is the ceiling of hvac/ducts/basement. No touching of hvac and ductwork. A new Lennox with new ductwork.

Just want to make sure okay to insulate with R19 in the floorboards which are exposed. No insulation. Floor of main house. The hvac sets on concrete slab in half a room with walls on 2 sides. It is not a full separate room.  Leads out onto rock and crawl space for rest of basement.

Floors are drafty in main house in winter. Thanks

Comment: Are the walls of the crawl space insulated and sealed?

Comment: The HVAC, ducts, etc should be WITHIN the insulated envelope, not out in the cold and/or heat.